# How to make view follow my image?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, ipod

Im making a scene for my game. Right now i`m working on the view for IPhone 5-5c-5s the orientation is in landscape. But the view was not big enough for my scene, so i made the simulated size to freeform so i could choose the width for the scene. (Im using a normal Viewcontroller).

In the game you are supposed to move an image to another image without colliding with obstacles. The users playing the app are going to move an image from one side of the screen all the way over to the other side to the other image to win.

But when my image moves, the view doesnt follow with my image. How do you do that?

I would be so thankful for any answear! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using SpriteKit yeah? The UIView size is not related to the scene size. So changing those will not make your scene any different.

To do what you are describing, you need to read the Apple's Official Documentation on SpriteKit.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Actions/Actions.html

Scroll down to **Example: Centering the Scene on a Node**

Basically Apple tells you to add a dummy SKNode to put all your world sprites into the scene, and then add another SKNode as "camera" into the dummy node so you can move it around.

If you are targetting only iOS9 and above, you can use SKCameraNode and set:

```
SKCameraNode *cameraNode = [SKCameraNode new];
cameraNode.name = @"camNode";
self.camera = cameraNode;
```

Then you add your "character" (that is to be moved together with the camera) into the cameraNode. Then any movement, you need to move the cameraNode instead of the "character".

Comment: Thanks for answear! Well im not using spritekit im actually using single view appliaction. But if i have to use spritekit ill do that :) Can you show me a complete code on how to do this? The character is an imageview that is moving around the screen :D

Comment: And is there any ways i can do this below ios 9? :D